# When uploading an image on Jelastic, the path does not persist in the database. It works fine on the localhost, however

Tags: java, image, spring, upload, jelastic

One of the requirements of the system is to be able to upload the profile picture of a user. It works fine in the localhost. The images I upload online are exactly the images that were successfully uploaded on the localhost. What could be the possible causes of such error?

This is the simplified code (the previous code I made was more complex, but it had no code repetition, and it ran faster. I simplified the code in order to trace the problem without luck, however)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patient_dp.it")
public String uploadPatientDP(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @ModelAttribute("form") ArchiveForm form, @RequestParam("id") long id, @RequestParam("key") String key) {
    System.err.println("patient dp");
    String username = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
    session.setAttribute("user", username);

    Patient patient = null; 

    try {
        patient = patientDao.getPatientById(id);
        MultipartFile file = form.getImages().get(0);           
        String absolutePath = null;
        String relativePath = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        String fileName_Original = null;
        if (file.getSize() > 0) {
            inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            if (file.getSize() > 100000) {
                System.out.println("File Size:::" + file.getSize());
                return "redirect:/upload_prof_pic_assembler?id=" + id + "&key=" + key;
            }
            fileName_Original = file.getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println("size::" + file.getSize());
            relativePath = "images/profilepic/" + fileName_Original;
            absolutePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "/" + relativePath;
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(absolutePath);
            System.out.println("fileName:" + file.getOriginalFilename());

            int readBytes = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
            while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 100000)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        }       

        patient.setRelativePath(relativePath);
        patient.setFileName(fileName_Original);
        patientDao.update(patient);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    return "redirect:/view_patient_profile.it?id=" + patient.getId();
}
```

In the upload pic jsp, which works fine

```
<c:when test="${patient != null }">
                        <form:form action="patient_dp.it?id=${patient.id }&key=p" method="post" commandName="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            Select File: <input type="file" name="images[0]" id="image" onSubmit="return Validate();"/>
                            <a href=""><span class="btn"><input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btnNew"></span></a>                     
                        </form:form>
                    </c:when>
```

This is an excerpt from the view-patient-profile.jsp file. Since the path of the image does not persist in the online database on Jelastic (mariadb), it diverts to the default image.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${patient.getRelativePath() == null || patient.getRelativePath().equalsIgnoreCase('null')}">
        <img src="resources/images/img_user.jpg" alt="">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <img src="${patient.getRelativePath() }" alt="${patient.getPersonInfo().getFirstName()}'s profile picture" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Is the problem about the path saved in the database (in which case please update your question with a sample path saved in the database, retrieved from phpMyAdmin), or the image saved in the filesystem (you can verify it in the Jelastic dashboard, or via SSH)?

Comment: @Damien-Layershift The path of the image was supposed to be saved in the database. However, nothing happens. On the localhost, the page is successfully redirected to the profile page with the display pic. Online, no error, but no pic either. Based on the code above, it's


relativePath = "images/profilepic/" + fileName_Original;
            absolutePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "/" + relativePath;

patient.setRelativePath(relativePath);
patient.setFileName(fileName_Original);
patientDao.update(patient);

Comment: So the file exists on the filesystem? (The file saving part is working fine?). It's purely about the path not getting saved or read properly from the database? Did you check that your database connection works? Maybe you're using localhost for the db connection string?